How to verify that the touchpad is physically connected
I need help troubleshooting the Synaptics touchpad on my HP Probook 4540s running Windows 10. First and foremost, how can I verify, by software or hardware (in that
order of preference), that the physical connection is proper so as to
eliminate that as the potential cause?
The touchpad stopped working altogether after my otherwise successful
repair of the notebook, during which I disconnected the ribbon cable that
connects it to the mainboard.  At first, I thought I had just forgotten to
reconnect the cable, which in fact I had.  But reconnecting it didn't help.
Then I thought the little blue plastic puller that had come unglued from
the cable's insulated side was needed to give the cable enough thickness to
fit snugly and make proper contact with the connector (see pictures
here,
although unlike in that case, my black locking tab is still intact and
functional), so I reattached it to the cable, but that did nothing. Much fiddling around with this connection (disconnecting and
reconnecting in slightly different ways) didn't help, either.
Windows' device manager reports that the device is "working properly" and
"plugged into PS/2 mouse port", but I've since found out that it is really
talking about the device
driver
and not the device itself.  Is there a way for me to check whether the
cable is properly connected so I don't keep fiddling forever if the problem
ends up being something else?
Although the cable connection is the most likely culprit here, there's a
possibility of a software cause.  When I first used the computer after the
repair, the internal microphone didn't work, either, because the audio
input was spontaneously changed to an external microphone.  So perhaps
something like that could've happened here, too.

If the cable is connected and the device doesn’t work then there likely is damage which will be impossible to diagnose without proper tools.

Check the manufacturer's web site for any diagnostic program(s) that might be available for downloading, e.g. https://support.hp.com/us-en/help/computer/keyboard-mouse-issues. Note that there's a video How to fix the touchpad on HP Notebooks running Windows 11 at the bottom of that web page.   (Gee, that seems to fit your predicament almost to a tee!) Also check your BIOS/UEFI settings.

The ribbon cable is the keyboard cable. The touchpad will have a different connector. Also, when a device is physicly missing as hardware, it will no longer show up in device manager unless you turn on hidden devices. The driver shouldnt even load when the device isnt detected. Your probook's touchpad has an indicator in the top left corner. Tapping that twice will enable or disable it.

@Silbee Are you sure about the device manager's only showing physically connected devices? It currently shows an external microphone, Bluetooth speakers, and the Focusrite USB interface, none of which is connected.  That said, it is true that when I disconnect the mouse, it disappears from the device manager.  The ribbon cable (smaller than that of the keyboard) is indeed for the touchpad, as you can see in the link provided in the original post. I've been double-tapping that top-left corner a bunch of times, to no avail.

Ah yes, my bad. The touchpad is indeed a smaller ribbon cable. The USB interface is connected even without a device connected to it. Same for an external microphone, it might show because the front panel audio connector is connected, not because there's a mic plugged into it. Wireless devices are different alltogether. So while i'm not 100% sure for every device, im 99% a touchpad (which is an input device) would only show up when its connected. Connected doesnt mean its fully functional per se tho, it might still be broken.
